# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'

Tags: selenium

I am getting an weird error for a specific URL. I am running selenium webdriver script using TestNG, eclipse, and Maven.

My test:

```
@TestNG
{
MyPage mypg = new MyPage(driver);
mypage.openURL();
}
```

Calls this method:

```
public void  openURL(){
//driver.get("http://www.site1.com/"); 
//driver.get("http://www.site2.com/"); 
driver.get("http://www.site3.com/"); 
System.out.println("Opened the URL");
}
```

When I run my test, site1 and site2 works just fine. It opens the URLS and then prints the message. 
However, when I run my test for site3, it opens site3.com and then status stays in running mode. It never prints the message "opened the URL" and running mode(red button) stays on. Then I see the below error. I am not sure why it is acting this way for site3. It works for site1 and site2. I updated the maven project. I restarted Eclipse. It did not help. Please advise.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot
>   determine loading status from unknown error: missing or invalid
>   'entry.level'   (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.29.461591
>   (62ebf098776g1772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT
>   140.10.155063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 1.29 seconds
>   Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'L-XP79550-A8198', ip: '1x2.1xx.1.1xx', os.name:
>   'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_131' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

I have a testng test. When I run the script, it opens URL and print message just fine. It d

Answer (score 0):

After adding the dependencies to pom.xml, site3.com worked. Still not sure why site1 and 2 worked without these dependencies but site3 did not work. At least now it worked.

maven-compiler-plugin
maven-surefire-plugin
webdrivermanager
selenium-chrome-driver

Comment: You never mentioned what your original dependencies were. This solution sounds like a fluke, and is probably unrelated to actual problem.